# How to add classes to the HTML module

Tags: dotnetnuke, stylesheet, rich-text-editor, dotnetnuke-5

I added an HTML module to my DotNetNuke page.  When I go into the editor for the module, there is a drop down "Apply CSS Class" that is empty with the exception of "Clear Class".  How do I create classes that I can use for the HTML module?  Where should any related CSS files reside in the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer, the latest versions of DNN are using a new provider for the HTML Module, Telerik's RadEditor.  DNN details on configuring the "Apply CSS Class" drop down can be found here: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/108/threadid/364908/scope/posts/Default.aspx

Comment: Also found another provider that really helps customize the RadEditor in DNN.  Easy to install and configure.  http://radeditor.codeplex.com/